# add column to existing table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table1 created in the prod environment. I have to add column to an existing table1.
Im using the function create of replace to create the table with the suitable ddl.
To add the column shall i add it manually on the prod machine and change the ddl.
Or changing only the ddl will do it?

Thank you

Comment: Please post your ddl function in question with the details of columns you want to add

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no such thing as a `create or replace table` syntax. that should only work for functions or views.

Use the `ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD NewColumn {DATA_TYPE}` command.

The way you phrased your question makes me think you use a 3rd party database version control like liquibase. If that is the case leave the initial create DDL alone and just add it as a separate change. If you change the initial ddl it will only affect new databases.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so i shall do both. first add the column on table1 of prod machine, second change the ddl  to include the new column. Is it what you mean @Gabriel Durac ? https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1046283935.1014.502.camel%40camel

Comment: So are you using liquibase or some other db versioning tool ?

Comment: im using postgresql

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` is a DDL command so I am a bit confused

Comment: what I am suggesting is just run the `ALTER TABLE` in prod and that will add the column. Also run the the same alter command on any other environments you want to add the column on. If you are running automatic db deploys using code, then you need to add a new changeset using the ALTER command.